# Typegraphql field that can be generic for any custom type

Tags: typescript, graphql, typegraphql

I have a typegraphql base interface and want to be able to have object types use this class with their own relationship/attribute types. Is there a way to create a custom type that accepts any typegraphql objecttype?

```
@InterfaceType()
export abstract class BaseObjectType {
    @Field(type => ID)
    id: string;

    @Field()
    type: string;

    @Field()
    relationships?: any;

    @Field()
    attributes?: any;

    @Field(() => MetaType)
    meta: MetaType;

    @Field(() => [LinkType])
    links: LinkType[];
}
```

Comment: Of course you can! See [`generic-types`](https://typegraphql.com/docs/generic-types.html)